# On mouse-over random on NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I developed an app for OS X 10.9 and OS X 10.10. This app has 2 view:

- Login view
- History view

In login view the user should only insert the username and password. When the user press on Login button it calls a web service to authorize the user to view the news.

When the user is logged, the app shows the History view in which are stored all news sent. To retrive this news it calls a web service to get a JSON with the history of all news. To display all news I used a `NSTableView`.

When the user move the mouse over a row of this `NSTableView` the background of the row became gray.

All is working quite fine, but to keep updated the news list I've to call the web service to get the history news every 10 second so I put the following code in my `HistoryViewController`:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(sendRequestToUrl) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

where `sendRequestToUrl` is the method to get the history from the web service. So every time it reload the list of news it shows me an over on a row without mouse over. Why's that?

To draw the mouse over I insert the following code in my custom cell class:

```
#import "HistoryCustomCell.h"

@implementation HistoryCustomCell {
    NSTrackingArea *_trackingArea;
    NSEvent *event;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self createTrackingArea];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
}

- (void)createTrackingArea {
    _trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited|NSTrackingActiveInActiveApp owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:_trackingArea];

    NSPoint mouseLocation = [[self window] mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
    mouseLocation = [self convertPoint:mouseLocation fromView:nil];

    if (NSPointInRect(mouseLocation, [self bounds])) {
        [self mouseEntered:nil];
    } else {
        [self mouseExited:nil];
    }
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self.onMouseOverImage setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"mouse_over_back_cell.png"]];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self.onMouseOverImage setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:nil]];
}

@end
```

Any idea why it doesn't working fine?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View-based table views re-use cell views for different cells (rows) at different times. So, once you set the image of one of your cell view's subviews, it will stay that way even if the cell view is removed from the table and then added back to the table to be used for a different cell.

You can try overriding `-prepareForReuse` and resetting everything that could have been customized back to its default state.

For what it's worth, you should generally specify `NSTrackingInVisibleRect` in the options of a tracking area that covers a whole view. That makes AppKit keep the tracking area updated to the view's on-screen position as it moves or changes size, especially if it's in a scroll view. Otherwise, you would have to override `-updateTrackingAreas` to remove and re-add the tracking area for the view's new position.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life with `-prepareForReuse`